# Como enviar imagen base64 a web services POST C#

Tags: c#, webservice, post, webforms, base64

Tengo un problema al tratar de consumir un servicio web tipo POST externo; me piden que envíe una imagen en base64, pero al enviarlo me lanza este error: System.UriFormatException: 'URI no válido: la cadena URI es demasiado larga.'esto sucede antes de enviar todos los datos al web services. la imagen pesa 30 kb.

```
List<string> Lista = new List<string>();
string url = "http://xxx.cti.lat/yyy/webservices/go.php";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.QueryString.Add("a", "pDepositos");
wc.QueryString.Add("idc", cueNatura);
wc.QueryString.Add("idop", idop);
wc.QueryString.Add("nrodoc", numOpe);
wc.QueryString.Add("fechadep", "2019/06/21");
wc.QueryString.Add("monto", montoDep);
wc.QueryString.Add("local", estable);
wc.QueryString.Add("det", "");
wc.QueryString.Add("tipopago", tipoDep);
wc.QueryString.Add("canales", "RED");
wc.QueryString.Add("imag64", imagenDep);

var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);
var responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic listaMove = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(responseString);
```

El error sucede en esta parte de mi codigo: var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres enviar un elemento complejo y  de longitud extensa, no puedes hacerlo por querystring, debes agregarlo como parte del cuerpo de tu llamada.

Comment: como podría hacerlo? tengo poca experiencia en consumir estos servicios.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que hay que entender es que en una llamada `POST` NO envías nada por QueryString; la única situación donde se usa es con llamadas `GET`. ¿Acaso pretendes que, en caso de usar un formulario de inicio de sesión, se pueda ver por URL el usuario y la contraseña para entrar? Te dejo una pequeña página donde [explican brevemente las diferencias entre GET y POST](https://difiere.com/la-diferencia-get-post/).

Una vez entendido eso, de acuerdo con la [documentación de WebClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadvalues?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_WebClient_UploadValues_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Specialized_NameValueCollection_) deberías sustituir esa `QueryString` por una *colección* de valores, usando un objeto de tipo `NameValueCollection`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
// En lugar de agregar los parámetros a una QueryString, añádelos a la colección:
nvc.Add("a", "pDepositos");
nvc.Add("idc", cueNatura);
nvc.Add("idop", idop);
nvc.Add("nrodoc", numOpe);
nvc.Add("fechadep", "2019/06/21");
nvc.Add("monto", montoDep);
nvc.Add("local", estable);
nvc.Add("det", "");
nvc.Add("tipopago", tipoDep);
nvc.Add("canales", "RED");
nvc.Add("imag64", imagenDep);

var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
```

Comment: Entiendo, aún me falta aprender más sobre web services. Utilicé el codigo de tu ejemplo pero me salta un error: Error del servidor remoto (500) error interno del servidor. Adjunto una imagen en mi pregunta.

Comment: @AntonioAriasFrancia [No puedo ver imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/) desde la red donde me conecto (trabajo), ¿puedes ser más claro?